# Java Selenium Switch ChromeDriver based on Chrome Version

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting below error when chromedriver doesn't match with chrome version.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot find context with specified id"}
```

(Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.186)
 Is there any way to switch chromedriver version based on chrome version by not doing it manually. It should detect based on chrome versions using java program. Since i am executing test on multiple machines which has different chrome versions.

Pls find below release link version of chromedriver compatibility 
[ChromeDriver release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can switch to respective chrome browser & chrome driver. You can implement as below.

1. configure compatible chromedriver and browser softweare file names
2. write the crone job or bat file (based on your OS) to uninstall the browser software (silent uninstall)
3. write the crone job or bat file to install the browser software required (silent installation) as mentioned in configuration
4. use/set desired chromedriver to launch the recently installed chrome browser

**Note: to run bat file, use Runtime API**

Comment: instead of uninstalling the browser can we switch to chromedriver as per chrome version. for eg. if one window machine has chrome version 60 so it should switch to chromedriver 34.